# How to use File Expert to select a file for upload in ubuntu-one on android?

Tags: ubuntu-one, android

When uploading files in U1 on android File Expert is the first choice that u1 offers me to select the uploaded file and its my first choice too.  But it doesn't work. While I can select files I don't know how to communicate this selection back to the U1-app.

In general it would be very useful to share whole folders on my sdcard to the cloud like my android would be a desktop-machine.

Answer (score 1):

Having tested using Ubuntu One for android and File Expert you can select which file you wish to upload by clicking "Add File" from within the Ubuntu One app, and selecting File Expert from the options given. Then simply navigate to the file you wish to upload and tap it. This will cause that file to be uploaded by the Ubuntu One app to your personal cloud.

In regard to the second point it isn't possible using File Expert to select a folder to upload, only selecting individual files will work.