# Why does Ubuntu One sync modified files just on one device?

Tags: ubuntu-one, android

The files on my PC are in sync with my Android tablet via **Ubuntu One**.

If I modify a file on my PC the changes are correctly sync'd to the tablet. However if I modify a file on my tablet, save it and sync it, it does not send the changed file back to the PC.

I have already checked my settings but couldn't find anything useful to solve this problem.

Comment: Please, could you specify how are you syncing the devices? Perhaps, are you using Ubuntu One?

Comment: yes with Ubuntu One

Comment: Can you tell me what kind of file have you modified? I find that usually it is text files, which we could start supporting, as it is one of the easiest use cases. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I'm the developer working on Ubuntu One Files. Allow me to assist you.

Ubuntu One Files does not sync your files. It is a thin client that gives you access to Ubuntu One cloud storage. It works quite differently from what you are used to on your desktop machine, due to a number of platform limitations on Android (such as battery, CPU and bandwidth). In other words, you can download and upload your files, none of these actions are automatic. You can also choose to auto-upload pictures, but this is far from a fully functional sync feature.

When the app detects the file has changed on the server, it removes the local file copy, so that you don't access the old file, and download the new one whenever you try to access it. However, if you modify the file, the app will not sync it back to Ubuntu One automatically. You would have to manually select to upload that file to the same location.

It is true that you need a file explorer (we currently don't ship a custom one), but it doesn't need to be File Expert. Actually, I suggest you give these a try:

- **ES File explorer** (the "File way" when you choose to share a file)
- **ASTRO file explorer**

You can use any file explorer of your choice, which properly shares a raw path of the chosen file (that's a technical bit, but there are a few file explorers that share content in an unsupported way with `content://` URIs).

That said, if you change a file, you would have to open Ubuntu One Files, browser to the destination directory, hit plus at the top, select **File**, and choose the file you have modified. The file will overwrite the copy on the server once uploaded.

**EDIT:** It is true that Ubuntu One stores your files under `SD_card_path/u1/` directory.

Comment: Please, do not insert comments or questions inside answers; instead comment on the original question. Check the bottom of the [first revision](http://askubuntu.com/revisions/72df1cb6-fbbb-4825-a716-edf0577fc715/view-source) of this post if you want to copy & paste your question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know the **Ubuntu One File** app for android does not do two-way sync. It only downloads the changed files from the server when you click on them.

To upload a file from the tablet you have to use a file management app like **File Expert**.

For example:

In File Expert, drill down to `SD Card` > `u1` > `Ubuntu One` or whatever folder has your file.

Select the file you have changed and choose **Share** and then choose **Ubuntu One File**. The file will get uploaded to Ubuntu One server.

Note: File Expert can be setup to directly work with Ubuntu One server without going through the Ubuntu One Files app. However, I have not tested that functionality of File Expert.

Also see: [How to use File Expert to select a file for upload in ubuntu-one on android?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/60755/how-to-use-file-expert-to-select-a-file-for-upload-in-ubuntu-one-on-android)

Hope this helps.